# Microsoft.CodeAnalysis: how do I ReplaceNodes into nodes of different NameSyntax type?

Tags: c#, tags, roslyn

.NET Framework 4.6.1 (and I should not change version)

I'm fixing a code that translates one language from one version into a newer one.

For this a property named like "LastBarIndexPainted" will have (I cannot change that) to be converted into "ChartBars.ToIndex", which causes an exception in the converter with error message:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.QualifiedNameSyntax' to type 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.SimpleNameSyntax'

because the words "LastBarIndexPainted" and "ChartBars.ToIndex" are syntactically different and **`the function CodeAnalysis.ReplaceNodes() only accepts to replace nodes into others of the **same** kind`**.

Being more specific, let's have a dictionary of replacements:

```
private Dictionary<string, string> _renamedProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "CalculateOnBarClose", "Calculate" },
    { "LastBarIndexPainted", "ChartBars.ToIndex" },
};
```

which is used by a converting function, whose code is:

```
private SyntaxNode ReplacePropertyNames(SyntaxNode node, Dictionary<string, string> propertyNameLookup)
{
    IEnumerable<NameSyntax> propertyIdentifiers = node
        .DescendantNodes()
        .OfType<NameSyntax>()
        .Where(n => propertyNameLookup.ContainsKey(n.ToString()));

    var replacements = new Dictionary<SyntaxNode, SyntaxNode>();
    SyntaxNode newIdentifierName2 = null;
    foreach (NameSyntax identifierName in propertyIdentifiers)
    {
        string newName = propertyNameLookup[identifierName.ToString()];
        SyntaxNode newIdentifierName = SyntaxFactory.ParseName(newName).WithTriviaFrom(identifierName);
        replacements.Add(identifierName, newIdentifierName); newIdentifierName2 = newIdentifierName;
    }

    return node.ReplaceNodes(replacements.Keys, (n, _) => replacements[n]);  # <== EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE
}
```

Again,

- with the first element of the dictionary we need to translate the word "CalculateOnBarClose" of type `Syntax.SimpleNameSyntax` into the word "Calculate" which has the same type `Syntax.SimpleNameSyntax`, and with this we don't have a crash.
- with the second element of the dictionary we need to translate the word "LastBarIndexPainted" of type `Syntax.SimpleNameSyntax` into the word "ChartBars.ToIndex" which has the same type `Syntax.QualifiedNameSyntax`, *because of the dot*, *and this causes a crash*.

How should I go about that?